# PHP foreach and JS change source changing wrong picture

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a gallery but when I press on one of the boxes that needs to put the image in a larger img it puts the wrong image in.

What it does right now:
[image]

And this is the code right now:

```
                <?php
                $hostname='localhost';
                $username='dddoecje_rik_cam';
                $password='*******';

                try {
                    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dddoecje_campu",$username,$password);

                    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                    $i = 0;
                    $len = count($array);
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
                    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
                    {
                        echo '
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                           <a>
                              <div onClick="change()" class="enlarge">
                                 <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              </div>
                              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"></img>
                           </a>
                           <script>
                              function change() {
                                  var image = document.getElementById("pic-big");
                                  image.src = "data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'";
                              }
                           </script>
                        </div>
    ';
                    }


                    $dbh = null;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                ?>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="picture">
            <img id="pic-big" src="assets/img/villa1.png" alt="Villa Big">
        </div>
```

Does someone know what causes this problem?

Comment: What causes what problem?It doesn't change?

Comment: The image doesn't change to image it needs to change to

Comment: Please add you ur JavaScripts too

Comment: I have. Check the function called "change"

Comment: Put the function out of foraech loop

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Don't mix javascript with php. Separate the javascript from the loop and it will make your life easy. :)

Comment: @L.Herrera Can you give an example on how I can do it without mixing JS and PHP

Comment: Your code is so messy But I Simplified it and answer your question If find it helpful and solves your problem you can accept it and it's also optional to click on up vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
 function change(src) {
 var image = document.getElementById("pic-big");
 image.src = "data:image/gif;base64,'"+src+"'";
               }
  </script> 
  <?php
  $hostname='localhost';
  $username='dddoecje_rik_cam';
  $password='*******';
            try {
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dddoecje_campu",$username,$password);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
  $i = 0;
  $len = count($array);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
  foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
  {
  echo '<div class="col-md-2"><a><div onClick="change(\'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).\')" class="enlarge"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"></img></a></div>';
                }
                $dbh = null;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
        <img id="pic-big" src="assets/img/villa1.png" alt="Villa Big">
    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. When I press an image it just does nothing

Comment: check your console

Comment: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script campi.nijdeken.com:1:7`

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in you code:
1.Don't use `</img>` img tag doesn't need that.
2.Define functions outside of loops.
3.You should call function in `image` not it's `div`.
4.Also you should add an argument to your function.
Small images:

```
$image_src = "data:image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'";
<img onClick="change(.$image_src.)" src=".$image_src.">
```

And your JavaScript function should be like this:

```
function change(img_src)
{
var image = document.getElementById("pic-big");
image.src = img_src;
}
```